How is one supposed to play these notes?
I was practicing Clair de Lune and noticed that throughout the entire piece there are certain note values that don't seem possible to play.
In this image I took from the end of Clair de Lune you can see that at the beginning of each staircase sequence there is a dotted quarter or dotted half note. But how would you hold these notes for the indicated duration considering all the other notes that need to be played in the sequence? I watched a few online performances and they don't play these specific notes with any extended duration so I'm a bit confused as to why they're there or what their purpose is.
Any explanation would be helpful, thanks.


With the aid of sostenuto pedal?

This may be of use: Piano sheet music: how to play this notation (pedals)?.

In absence of a sostenuto pedal, it should be possible to use the left hand to hold the dotted quarter and the right to play the staircase sequence?

This has to be a dupe. It's been the source of many similar questions where pieces have been transcribed for piano.

@Tim What makes you believe that Debussy’s Clair de Lune was transcribed for piano?

@Lazy - not this example necessarily, but so many others have that same syndrome.

@Tim Okay, sounded to me like you were suggesting that Clair de Lune was a transcription of an orchestral piece or something. In fact this piece is written by a pianist for piano, and what we see here is well playable and actually has long tradition in piano music (in some form even older than the fortepiano itself). This is not your typical musescore.com arrangement that sounds good on playback, but is impossible to execute!

The notes you see are the bass line, which should be clear and distinguishable. This does not mean you’ll need to press the key continuously, and you can can make use of the pedal to keep the notes ringing. Of course you want to avoid drowning the piece in pedal, but find a combination of accentuation, fingering, and light pedaling to make it sound good.
And this can differ by pianist. Some pianists will not hold the key and just use heavy pedalling:



Some pianists split the notes between left and right hand (so left: 5-2-1 right: 1-2-5), which allows holding the note, so you can be lighter an pedal and achieve a lighter, more transparent sound:



The former version to play it of course has the advantage to be the same as mm. 27+, which features this accompaniment, but with melody, so you have to take a least the 10th into the left hand:






That being said, you can do a mixture: Instead of playing the first 4 notes in the left hand as 5-3-2-1 you can do 5-2-1-2, which allows to hold the bass a bit longer, thus using the pedal a bit later, and avoid the low fifth in sustain. But that is a bit tricky.
Also keep in mind that Debussy was very keen on playing with the pedal, so instead of thinking of the pedal as on-off, think of it as something you can use gradually (half-pedaling). By typical construction of pianos the pedal raises the dampers using a stick on the bass side of the instrument. This means that with some feeling you can use the pedal in a way that affects the lower notes more than the higher notes. You can also use such effects to keep you sound more transparent. But note that this tends to work less well on modern pianos, maybe build with too much precision ...

Great comment there on early modern piano damper with a stick in the bass side; another dimension that a 21st pianist should consider when discerning pianist composer intention.

This is where the sostenuto pedal comes into play.
On a lot of pianos, there is a centre pedal which is not a practice pedal, but a special sort of sustain pedal. It's designed to only sustain the note/s played when it's deployed. So rather than use the right hand sustain pedal all through, to keep those bass notes sounding when one really has to let go of the key, the sostenuto is the tool of choice.
Using it with correct timing, it will simply allow the bass note to continue, without muddying the rest of the fairly quick notes which follow. That way, the whole lot comes over cleanly, but the bass lasts for the written time - usually the dotted crotchet.
The sostenuto pedal is commonplace in US, whereas in Europe, if there's a central pedal, it brings a curtain down between the hammers and the strings, thus dampening the sound for practice. With that in mind, I'm trying to find out whether Debussey's piano would have had the afore mentioned sostenuto pedal...
Turns out the sos. pedal had its debut in Paris in 1844, and was perfected by Steinway by 1874. Since Clair de Lune was written in 1882, there's a fair chance it could have been used by Claude.
EDIT: Having listened to a recording of Debussy playing Debussy, I'm of the opinion that he actually used the sustain pedal to keep the bass notes going.

I'm in the UK. I've seen plenty of pianos with centre pedals, but never one with a "practice" pedal: they've all been sostenuto.

@AndrewLeach - I find that incredible. Unless we're discussing grands as all the studio (uprights) I've seen have the centre pedal operating that curtain.

Admittedly far fewer uprights, but yes, even those. Perhaps they were more expensive than educational establishments might usually pay for. But they were in dedicated soundproofed practice rooms, so...

Debussy (while most likely aware of it) did not really play pianos with sostenuto pedal, and he never actually mentions it. On the other hand Debussy likes to talk about “the two pedals”, which to me indicates that the third pedal would not really have been on his mind. Of course, Debussy would have played quite different pianos anyway, so no point in being overzealous. Also modern grand pianos almost always come with sostenuto pedal, but in the past many pianos would just have 2 pedals. A moderator on a pedal is a relatively recent thing and replaces a stop on the sides of mostly uprights.

In addition to @Lazy's wonderful response:
Having enjoyed (attempted?) playing "Claire de Lune" over many decades (non-professionally), there are some obvious practical points that one learns...
Namely, right, it's maybe not possible to make everything as legato/sustained as might be suggested by the score... or as one might imagine.
So, duh, at least for amateurs, there are trade-offs. That's the point, for me. To go all-out in one measure may wreck the next. So, think about what you want... in the situation where you cannot have everything. :)
(It's a wonderful piece, in any case.)
